# How to input some values automatically after I run one bat script?

Tags: batch-file

I think I see how to input one value to the script, just like

```
echo oracle | sip_sample.bat
```

but now I want to input more values in the bat file, because there are many values which are needed to be input after I run the script.

So could you someone help me work it out?

Comment: What do you mean by "input more values"? Do you want to pass some variables to a bat file so that they be available in your batch code?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I mean I need to input some values after calling the batch file. They are not variables.

Comment: I need to input more than one value to finish the script. What the batch file do is to create some users in oracle, so we need to input name, password, and other info, so I need automatically inputting some values.

Comment: `(echo oracle & echo name & echo password) | sip_sample.bat`

Comment: Thanks Aacini. It is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values to your batch script similar to below

```
sip_sample.bat  "oracle"
```

Now in order to use this value passed to the script , you need to use either %1 or %~1 inside you batch script

feel free to add your comments if you require additional information.

Comment: Hi my friend, I think I cannot edit the sip_sample.bat , it is so complicated that I am not able to find where to add the variable. So do you have any better idea except this one? Any input is great.